# error when run zepplin connecting aws glue

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-zeppelin, aws-glue

I following the tutorial steps as show in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/dev-endpoint-tutorial-local-notebook.html

There's no issue connection between local zepplin to AWS Glue. However when I run test command on zepplin it gives me error

```
%pyspark
import sys
org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:266)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:250)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:373)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:97)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:406)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:329)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Log from spark server

```
ERROR [2019-09-24 12:45:09,757] ({pool-2-thread-8} Job.java[run]:188) - Job failed
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:401)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:97)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:406)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:329)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:266)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:250)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:373)
    ... 11 more
ERROR [2019-09-24 12:45:09,774] ({pool-2-thread-8} RemoteScheduler.java[getStatus]:281) - Unknown status
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum constant org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.Status.UNKNOWN
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:238)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job$Status.valueOf(Job.java:51)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobStatusPoller.getStatus(RemoteScheduler.java:271)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:342)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
ERROR [2019-09-24 12:45:09,775] ({pool-2-thread-8} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2056) - Error
org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:401)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.interpret(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:97)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:406)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:175)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:329)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TIOStreamTransport.read(TIOStreamTransport.java:132)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransport.readAll(TTransport.java:86)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readAll(TBinaryProtocol.java:429)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readI32(TBinaryProtocol.java:318)
    at org.apache.thrift.protocol.TBinaryProtocol.readMessageBegin(TBinaryProtocol.java:219)
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:69)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.recv_interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:266)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.thrift.RemoteInterpreterService$Client.interpret(RemoteInterpreterService.java:250)
    at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.interpret(RemoteInterpreter.java:373)
    ... 11 more
 WARN [2019-09-24 12:45:09,775] ({pool-2-thread-8} NotebookServer.java[afterStatusChange]:2064) - Job 20190924-110806_1690051421 is finished, status: ERROR, exception: org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.InterpreterException: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException, result: org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException
 INFO [2019-09-24 12:45:09,783] ({pool-2-thread-8} SchedulerFactory.java[jobFinished]:137) - Job paragraph_1569294486122_1120959405 finished by scheduler org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterexisting_process1435285773
```

Any idea where's going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved it by selecting older version Spark 2.2 when creating dev endpoint

[image]

Comment: glad able to help :)

Answer (score 5):

AWS seems to have updated their endpoints to support the newer versions of the Zepplin notebook and the newer glue versions--but they have not updated their AWS Glue dev endpoint documentation to state as such. 
[AWS Glue dev endpoint documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ASmUb.png)

If you're running Zepplin version 0.7.3 you need to initialize your endpoint with **Glue Version Spark 2.2 (Glue Version 0.9)**--as Conandor stated.

If however you want to run the recent Zepplin version 0.8.2 it will work with development endpoint **Spark 2.4 Python 3 (Glue Version 1.0)**.

Answer (score 1):

I am getting the same exact issue, and have not resolved it. However I did go through some troubleshooting steps:

- Restart zeppelin with:

```
sudo bash
./zeppelin-daemon stop
lsof -t -i tcp:8080 | xargs kill # Had to use this when zeppelin wouldn't die
./zeppelin-daemon start
```

- Reinstall zeppelin entirely, ensure previous config is not loaded
- Check java version. Zeppelin only supports Java 8 with:

```
java -version
```

- Check zeppelin version. AWS Glue only supports 0.7.3

If you happen to find the solution, PLEASE POST IT!!!!!

I can't comment on your answer but if that solves the issue, you're a God. You saved us hours of dev time (running these jobs in python scripts, waiting for cold start times).

Answer (score 0):

If you faced with TTransportException that is means that Zeppelin is not able to connect to a metastore.

You need to specify "Catalog options".

[image: Glue]

Now you can use Spark 2.4, Python 3 and Zeppelin 0.8

Answer (score 0):

This cost me hours of time - for me it was another process that was tying up my tunnel port 9907.  I used `lsof -i :9907` and `kill -9 PID` to kill the process on 9907, then reconnected to the dev endpoint and it started behaving as expected.